# correct usage of cookies with curl command?

Tags: curl, cookies

I am trying to use curl command with cookies.

So first I do:

```
curl -c /path/to/cookie myurl1
```

This generates a cookie on assigned path.

Now I want to use this cookie to call next url from same server:

```
curl -b /path/to/cookie myurl2
```

But I get '401' error.

It seems my understanding of these commands is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?